# How do I create a triangulated surface from points?

Tags: plotting, functions, matrix, numerical-integration, geometry

I have a set of points in a nx3 matrix and I would like to convert them into a surface, so that I may calculate its surface area.

The function ListSurfacePlot3D creates the surface how I want it. How do I compute the surface area from there?
[image]

I have tried other functions, such as DelaunayMesh. However, DelaunayMesh creates a closed region defining a volume, causing the surface area to be greater than expected. Which function do I use? If this surface is created correctly, I would use RegionMeasure to get the area.
[image]

Edit: Here is my set of data points
https://www.dropbox.com/s/db79ewahx24it3r/Data.txt?dl=0

Using Geomagic Control allows me to get the area of the wrapped points, at about 11522 mm2. I don't need the visual, I only want the area from these points. 
[image]

I'll be running the area calculation through a routine of about 6000 samples.

Comment: See `DiscretizeGraphics` and `TriangulateMesh`. You should also provide a sample data if you want people to pay attention and provide help.

Comment: I have added a sample of my data. It appears triangulate mesh only triangulates an existing surface, so I couldn't use that.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It turns out `ListSurfacePlot3D` does a terribly poor job of approximating the surface in the OP, otherwise one will just apply `DiscretizeGraphics` to the output obtained from `ListSurfacePlot3D` and be done with it. But since that's not applicable here, we present an approach that uses alpha shapes to approximate the shape of the given point set by tuning a parameter. First a helper function for computing the circum-radius of a tetrahedron (we `Compile` it and give it the `Listable` `Attribute` for speed gains):

```
circumRadius = 
 Compile[{{v, _Real, 2}}, 
  With[{a = v[[1]] - v[[4]], b = v[[2]] - v[[4]], c = v[[3]] - v[[4]]},
   With[{a1 = Plus @@ (a^2), b1 = Plus @@ (b^2), c1 = Plus @@ (c^2),
     α1 = b[[2]] c[[3]] - b[[3]] c[[2]], 
     α2 = b[[3]] c[[1]] - b[[1]] c[[3]], 
     α3 = b[[1]] c[[2]] - b[[2]] c[[1]],
     β1 = c[[2]] a[[3]] - c[[3]] a[[2]], 
     β2 = c[[3]] a[[1]] - c[[1]] a[[3]], 
     β3 = c[[1]] a[[2]] - c[[2]] a[[1]],
     γ1 = a[[2]] b[[3]] - a[[3]] b[[2]], 
     γ2 = a[[3]] b[[1]] - a[[1]] b[[3]], 
     γ3 = a[[1]] b[[2]] - a[[2]] b[[1]]},
    Norm[a1 {α1, α2, α3} + b1 {β1, β2, β3} + c1 {γ1, γ2, γ3}] / 
         (2 Norm[Plus @@ (a[[1 ;; 3]] {α1, α2, α3})])]
   ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True]
```

And now the code to compute the alpha shape:

```
alphaShapes[points_, crit_] := 
 Module[{alphacriteria, del = Quiet @ DelaunayMesh @ points, tetras, 
         tetcoords, tetradii, selectExternalFaces}, 
  alphacriteria[tetrahedra_, radii_, rmax_] := 
         Pick[tetrahedra, UnitStep @ Subtract[rmax, radii], 1]; 
  selectExternalFaces[facets_] := MeshRegion[points, facets]; 
  If[Head[del] === EmptyRegion, del, 
      tetras = MeshCells[del, 3]; 
      tetcoords = MeshPrimitives[del, 3][[All, 1]]; 
      tetradii = Quiet@circumRadius@tetcoords /. ComplexInfinity -> $MaxMachineNumber; 
      selectExternalFaces @ alphacriteria[tetras, tetradii, crit]
   ]
 ]
```

For the plot, setting `crit` to $45$ seems to do a good job, but there appear to be holes in the surface. The area appears to be close to the value posted by OP from Geomagic.

```
reg = RegionBoundary @ alphaShapes[data, 45]; (* data is your nx3 matrix *)
HighlightMesh[reg, {Style[2, FaceForm[None]], Style[1, Darker@Green]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is the approximate area:

```
0.5 Area @ reg
```

> 11612.

Which is very close to `11522` (the value provided by the OP). Note that I'm dividing the total area by $2$ since the `Area` function will compute the areas of the cells on both sides of the image.

**For the Image Gurus here:**

I would like to know if *Mathematica* can produce something as nice as the image posted in the question obtained from GeoImage.

Comment: Unfortunately, `ListSurfacePlot3D` does a pretty poor job of approximating this surface.  Try running `Show[ListSurfacePlot3D[data], ListPointPlot3D[data]]` to see how bad.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert. Indeed, it does a poor job.

Comment: Maybe your code is computing the total area of a two-sided surface?

Comment: @Rahul, That's what I thought, I guess that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: I successfully used your code to generate alpha shapes for point sets. What is the name of the algorithm your used in the implementation? Is there a publication/work that can be cited for the algorithm/implementation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @g3kk0. I'm glad you found my code useful. You can look up Edelsbrunner's Algorithm, which is what I implemented.

Comment: https://datarepository.wolframcloud.com/resources/Stanford-Bunny

If you use ListSurfacePlot3D[data, MaxPlotPoints -> 50], it will work nicely and fit the ListPointPlot3D[data]