# Non-convex hull mesh from 3d points

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, geometry, computational-geometry, mesh

I am trying to create a 3d mesh object from list of points, but the only options I see in Mathematica are `ConvexHullMesh` and `DelaunayMesh` which do not fit my needs since they lead to an effect show in the figure below. I need something like non-convex Hull similar to what is typically shown on `ListSurfacePlot3D`. I need an object itself since I want to calculate its volume and intersection with other figures. Is it possible in Mathematica?

[image]

Comment: Might help: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86196/38178

Comment: also related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8753/9490