# Alternatives for `GradientFittedMesh` and `ReconstructionMesh` in older versions

Tags: computational-geometry

Are there similar functions to [`GradientFittedMesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GradientFittedMesh.html) and [`ReconstructionMesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReconstructionMesh.html), which were introduced in v13, for generating mesh point cloud surfaces in older versions of Mathematica (e.g. v12.2)? Perhaps in the [Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository)?

Comment: There is [`NonConvexHullMesh`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/NonConvexHullMesh/) in the WFR which, I believe, uses alpha shapes method that is also available in `ReconstructionMesh[..., Method -> "AlphaShape"]`. Also, there are a few questions on this SE about concave hulls ([example 1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8753/finding-a-concave-hull), [example 2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86196/how-do-i-create-a-triangulated-surface-from-points)).

Comment: @Domen Thanks, I know  `ResourceFunction["NonConvexHullMesh"][]` which is a good start for this kind of problems. But it's very sensitive

Comment: Maybe it's time for an update ;-)

Comment: @user21 As a pensioner, a frequent update should be well considered ;-)